# Collect all boost fusion map keys into a std::tuple

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/value_at_key.hpp>
#include <tuple>

struct MyEvents {
    struct EventA;
    struct EventB;
    using EventMap = boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<EventA, int>,
                                        boost::fusion::pair<EventB, double>>;
};

template <typename T>
struct GetTypes;

template <typename T>
struct GetTypes<boost::fusion::map<...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<...>;
};

int main() {
    using Map = typename MyEvents::EventMap;
    using AllKeys = GetTypes<Map>::type;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qx3WeYefY)

I want to collect all key types from a `boost::fusion::map` into a `std::tuple`.

The keys in this snippet are `MyEvents::EventA` and `MyEvents::EventB`, so `AllKeys = std::tuple<MyEvents::EventA, MyEvents::EventB>`.

How could one do this with template specialization? Do I need some kind of recursive calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the key type of `boost::fusion::pair` by using `T::first_type`.

```
template <typename T>
struct GetTypes;

template <typename... Pairs>
struct GetTypes<boost::fusion::map<Pairs...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<typename Pairs::first_type...>;
};
```

[Demo.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4esv63Mvz)